# how to get a text from long audio using google speech to text node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, google-speech-api

I follow the guidelines from official docs Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API but I keep on receiving an error:

> starting-account-.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not
>   have storage.objects.get access to .

```
  const client = new speech.SpeechClient();
  const gcsUri = bucket uri;
  const encoding = 'LINEAR16';
  const sampleRateHertz = 16000;
  const languageCode = 'en-US';
  const config = {
    encoding: encoding,
    sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
    languageCode: languageCode
  };
  const audio = {
    uri: gcsUri
  };

  const request = {
    config: config,
    audio: audio
  };

  const [operation] = await client.longRunningRecognize(request);
  // Get a Promise representation of the final result of the job
  console.log('operation', operation);
  const [response] = await operation.promise();
  const transcription = response.results
    .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
    .join('\n');
  console.log(`Transcription: ${transcription}`);
```

What should I do to get the access?

Comment: Please read this [ask]...
Anyway you have gcloud permissions issue, it's not a code issue

Answer (score 1):

For google cloud speech-to-text:

The documentation recommends .wav files at 16000Hz

`16bit 16000Hz mono .wav` has worked for me.

I take my original recording (or rip from video) and do a pass with some EQ and voice limiting effects (with freeware Audacty, or Adobe Audition) then `save as` the format above — then upload that to gc storage, then run `ml speech` on it.

You can also use the `alpha` version of `ml speech` … it has  few more flags that help the AI with transcription. My command looks like this:

`gcloud alpha ml speech recognize-long-running gs://my-bucket/my-audio-16bit-16k.wav --language-code=en-US --enable-automatic-punctuation --sample-rate=16000 --max-alternatives=1 --interaction-type=dictation --original-media-type=video --recording-device-type=pc --naics-code=541613 > my-transcript.txt`

… you see I write the output into a `.txt`

Here is the documentation on the alpha: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/ml/speech/recognize-long-running

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the `alpha` command. That was helpful. Didn't find it documented anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

As the error you’re getting states, your **service account** doesn’t have `storage.objects.get` [**permission**](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles).

The issue can be solved by granting your service account a relevant **role** *(like `roles/storage.objectViewer`)*. As Google Cloud Platform [**documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts#granting_access_to_a_service_account_for_a_resource) states, you can grant it the following way:

> 1. Open the [**IAM & Admin**](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/iam-admin?_ga=2.241081030.-49166597.1566805838) page in the GCP Console.
> 2. Select your project and click **Continue**.
> 3. **Identify the service account** to which you want to add a role.
> 4. *If the service account isn't already on the members list*, it doesn't
>      have any roles assigned to it. Click **Add** and enter the email address
>      of the service account.
> 5. *If the service account is already on the members list*, it has existing roles. Click the **drop-down list** under **Role(s)** for the
>      service account that you want to edit.
> 6. Select one or more roles to apply to the service account.
> 7. Click **Add** or **Save** to apply the roles to the service account.

Alternatively, you can authenticate using another service account that has the relevant permissions.